# Table like structure with at least 1 div filling rest of the page AND keeping auto height AND filling div wraping long text WITHOUT javascript

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to create this "table-like" design with 3 requests:

[image]

I found out how to solve the problem with div filling the rest of the page: 
set row div relative position and child divs absolute position and set left div to: position: 0;width: 100px; middle div to left: 100px; width 100%; right: 100px; and right div to right: 0; width: 100px;

But this solution have the other 2 problems - 100% width div does not wrap long text and height of divs have to be some fixed value.

Btw I dont require the use of divs, it can be created with table but I wasn't able to convince tables to fill "the rest of the space".

I mean this is realy basic behaviour I want from my UI so why is it so hard to create it with HTML+CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `display: table;` and `table-cell` for the div

```css
.wrap { 
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.wrap > div { 
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;/*remove after inner dom creating*/
}
.wrap > div.fixed {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will have a look at it once in office. I tryed this idea with tables before and it didn't work so I didnt even try to do the same with divs. Definately gonna try it, thanks.

Comment: It is working - just add "overflow-wrap: break-word;" to .wrap > div {} and it behaves as I wanted

Comment: btw - I usually need only 1 column filling the rest of the space but I was thinking what if I need 2 columns and lets say 1st should fill 30% and second 70% of the space left - thats impossible with HTML + CSS only right? (I still want to keep other columns with fixed width ofc)

Comment: oh nvm - I just found answer by myself. It is possible to do another table in that cell - you need 1 extra div for that but it is simple and quite elegant

Comment: I am starting to like div tables. So far I had troubles with non standard UI with HTML+CSS but unlike "absolute/relative" position magic and other hacks/tricks, where is usually very hard to predict behaviour, table divs are intuitive